# How to sort the date inside a string?

Tags: r

I have a few file names which include dates and I need to sort them in numerical order, for example:

```
dates=c("8_18_2016.xlsx","8_25_2016.xlsx","8_4_2016.xlsx")
```

and I want to sort it out to:

```
> dates
"8_4_2016.xlsx"  "8_18_2016.xlsx"  "8_25_2016.xlsx"
```

Thanks

Comment: Mixed sort is a [slightly contentious] thing: `gtools::mixedsort(c("8_18_2016.xlsx", "8_25_2016.xlsx", "8_4_2016.xlsx"))`

Comment: @alistaire this is awesome dude! thanks

Comment: @alistaire this might be a problem if more than one year is represented. Try `gtools::mixedsort(c("8_18_2016.xlsx", "8_25_2015.xlsx", "8_4_2016.xlsx"))` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to find the order by creating a separate vector, where the values are converted to date format:

```
dates.order <- order( as.Date( dates, format = "%m_%d_%Y.xlsx" ) )
```

Then use that to sort your original vector:

```
sorted <- dates[ dates.order ]
sorted
[1] "8_4_2016.xlsx"  "8_18_2016.xlsx" "8_25_2016.xlsx"
```